# How to avoid high page response time when test ends

Tags: jmeter

Sometimes when a JMeter test ends I've found the max page response times spike up. Has anyone else noticed this? If so how do you prevent this from happening?

Comment: how long does your test last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is too short, a load test should last at minimum 30 minutes, nothing can be concluded from long response times at end of tesf as we don't know your load test profile.

Anyway it is not a JMeter known issue and may reveal an application issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll run some further tests and see how it goes.

Comment: I know the rules :-) Let me do some further testing first. I may have more questions. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, a longer run produced better results.

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK Why do you believe test should run for not less then half an hour?